# What is the syntax for an HTML Tag inline IF Condition MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a `<select>` tag that has its `<option>` tags built via a loop.

I am confused on how to properly use the Razor syntax for setting the `selected` attributed for an `<option>` that meets a condition.

The code below is an example of my understanding on how to do this...

```
<select>
@{
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {                        
   <option value="@i" @if(Model.Foo == i){ @:selected }>@i</option>
  }
 }
</select>
```

However, the code above incurs a design-time error that states:

> The for block is missing a closing "}" character. Make sure you have a
>   matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block,
>   and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.

Inferring from the error message, I'm assuming that the closing curly brace that comes directly after `@:selected` is being *interpreted as markup*.

I can fix the error if/when I put a new-line prior to the offending curly brace like this...

```
<select>
@{
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {                        
   <option value="@i" @if(Model.Foo == i){ @:selected 
    }>@i</option>
  }
 }
</select>
```

Is there a proper Razor syntax that doesn't require a new-line?

FYI - I've tried using the `<text>selected</text>` tag to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following should work.

```
value="@(Model.Foo == i ? "selected" : "")"
```